# Pulling data from Sheets API via Python and Django issue

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

on the local host (using virtualenv) but it kept giving me the message below and

I kept hearing that it might be because of the Oauth2 Error?

> Performing system checks...
>
> usage: manage.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME] [--noauth_local_webserver]
>                        [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
>                        [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
>
> manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver

I'm adding my the Python code that I'm using (it's some what an example code from [Google Sheets API V4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python))

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

def get_form_data():
    SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
    RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                             range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    data = []

    if not values:
        return data
    else:
        for row in values:
            data.append([])
            for each in row:
                data[len(data)-1].append(each.encode("utf-8"))
        return data
```

Has anyone ever run into this problem before and solve the issue? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome! Can you tell us what line is causing the error?

Comment: I honestly don't know what really caused the error since the actual python script is working when I run it on my Mac. Additionally I imported this python script to views.py. Other simple scripts such as a hello world works normally, but not for this particular script. It's not working when I tried to run -> _python manage.py runserver_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Calendar API stops Django from starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758516/google-calendar-api-stops-django-from-starting)

Comment: I'm not quite sure the usage of the flag for that particular issue and I don't have it in my script. Care to explain? thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the sample code from Google. Where exactly did you add this to your django code?